# How to display my message using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
requireValidPassword: check("password")
    .trim()
    .custom(async (password, { req }) => {
      const user = await usersrepo.getoneby({ email: req.body.email });
      if (!user) {
        throw new Error("Invalid password");
      }
      const validPassword = await usersrepo.comaparepass(
        user.password,
        password
      );
      if (!validPassword) {
        throw new Error("invalid password");
      }
    }),
```

im using js code to check if the user entered the correct password while signing in.But if the user enters a wrong password the error-- **The "salt" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined** is shown instead of "**invalid password**"

Comment: okay, and where is the `salt` variable required? obviously not in the code you provided... probably somewhere in your `usersrepo.comaparepass`-function

Comment: `async comaparepass(saved, supplied) {
    const [hashed, salt] = saved.split(".");
    const hashedsupplies = await scrypt(supplied, salt, 64);

    return hashed === hashedsupplies.toString("hex");
  }`